# How to run async form in background without deadlocking

Tags: .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

Run Async Form in Background without deadlocking

FormA (see example below) is old and loads slowly due to lots of lazy-loading EF6 code etc. We've managed to speed it up with some async methods that allow the form to at least be displayed whilst loading data. Async all the way up to the event handlers is working nicely - UNTIL: the same form is loaded in the background by a second form (FormB) that loops through and loads the form for multiple records in order to run some checks over the data as it loads (yeah not at all ideal, but not going there now).

Before the async changes, FormA was being created in a method on FormB started using `Thread.Start(...)` - now we've reworked to be async all the way up to the Button_Click event handler that started the mass update process, but FormA is now hogging the UI thread so FormB never updates any progress indicators until everything is finished.

We've tried using `Task.Run(...)` to create instances of FormA and do its work, but we always get a deadlock on the first `await asyncMethod(...)` in FormA. The lowest level of those async methods do use `ConfigreAwait(False)`, but the upper levels don't because there are UI Components that need to be updated after retrieving data from the database which must happen on the same thread that created the form and its controls.

FormA has this sort of code

```
    public partial class FormA : Form
    {
        private int _counter;

        public FormA(int counter)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _counter = counter;
        }

        private async void formDoWork_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Loading...";
            await Task.Delay(5000); // Various async tasks happen here
            this.Text = "Loaded";
        }

        public async Task LoadDataAsync()
        {
            this.workingLabel.Text = "Working...";
            string result = await GetDataAsync(); // Get the data but can't ConfigureAwait(false) because we need to update UI components afterwards
            this.workingLabel.Text = "Finished! " + result;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
        {
            // Get the data from the database - we can ConfigureAwait(false) here because no UI components are updated at this level (in real code this would be in a separate data layer library)
            await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return $"Loading #{_counter}";
        }
    }
```

Then in FormB we do something like this:

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public FormB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GoButton.Enabled = false;
        var activeTasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Start processing form asynchronously and keep track of the task for later
            Task processTask = ProcessFormAsync(i);
            activeTasks.Add(processTask);
            this.ProgressLabel.Text = $"Started #{i}";
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        // Wait for all the tasks to be finished, then update progress on UI
        await Task.WhenAll(activeTasks);

        this.ProgressLabel.Text = "Finished.";
        this.GoButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async Task ProcessFormAsync(int counter)
    {
        using (var newForm = new FormA(counter))
        {
            // Show the form to trigger form_Load event handler and then hide it again
            newForm.Show();
            newForm.Hide();

            // Now call the main Load function which is also async.
            await newForm.LoadDataAsync();
            newForm.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And all works well, except that everything (besides the continuation of `FormA.GetDataAsync`) is running on the Main UI thread

```
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 0 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 0 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 1 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 1 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 0 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 2 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 2 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 1 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 3 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 3 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 2 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 4 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 4 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 3 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 5 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 5 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 4 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 6 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 6 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244)  | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 5 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 7 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 7 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 6 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 8 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 8 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 7 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13984) | 9 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Main Thread(7244) | 9 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 8 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Main Thread(7244) | 9 <<<
The program '[17808] AsyncWinForms.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

In our real scenario  FormA is so busy doing UI work it means that nothing on FormB is updated until the end of the processing which defeats the purpose of updating progress. So we've tried to change it to run FormA on a bacgkround thread like this:

```
Task processTask = Task.Run(async () => await ProcessForm(i).ConfigureAwait(false)));
```

And FormB now gets to update progress, but FormA deadlocks on any `await ...Async` method calls.

Deadlocking Output:

```
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 0 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 1 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 2 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 3 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 0 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 4 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(12084) | 1 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 5 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(12084) | 2 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(12084) | 3 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 6 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(11596)  | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(11596) | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 4 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(11596) | 7 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(13184)  | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(12084) | 5 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 8 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.formDoWork_Load(object, System.EventArgs) | Worker Thread(11596)  | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.LoadDataAsync() | Worker Thread(11596) | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(13184) | 6 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(11596) | 9 >>>
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(11596) | 7 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(1548) | 8 <<<
AsyncWinForms.FormA.GetDataAsync() | Worker Thread(12084) | 9 <<<
The thread 0x60c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2f34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3380 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6036] AsyncWinForms.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Why is this happening? We can't see anything that is blocking the new worker threads, but it deadlocks everytime. What alternatives do we have?

Comment: _and loads the form for multiple records in order to run some checks over the data as it loads_ - Why you need to load a form for checking the data, load only data?

Comment: @Fabio as mentioned, the why is not up for discussion here, that's just the way it needs to be for now. Yes, the form needs to be rewritten to separate out business logic from UI logic, but that is a way bigger task than what we have time/budget to do right now. When that eventually gets done we won't need to do this workaround, but until then we do and that's what we're asking for help with.

Comment: I afraid you will continue dealing with "small" issues like this until you extract not UI related logic out of the form.

Comment: You can consider my comment above as an excuse not to dig into the details of your question, sorry.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PauloMorgado Did I miss something? If you copy the two code snippets above into a standard WinForms Application, you'll have all that you need to replicate the problem.

Comment: @bmadtiger: _"Did I miss something?"_ -- yes, you did. It is not sufficient to provide a complete example. You are also required to provide a **minimal** example.

Comment: @bmadtiger - All Winforms forms and controls must be created, accessed and updated from the single UI thread. You can only do purely non-UI work on other threads. You need to re-architect what you're doing.

Comment: @Enigmativity - interestingly the original code before we updated FormA with `async`/`await` code ran on a background thread using `Thread.Start(...)` and had no problems running "UI code" on a background thread doing that, so why would it be different with `async`/`await`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not sure how much more minimal I can get and still replicate the issue? Please give more specific instructions on how to refine my question.

Comment: @bmadtiger - It's a bit like riding a motorbike without a helmet. You might say, "Hey, I didn't get brain damage?" It's just a matter of time until there's a crash. Just because `Thread.Start` seemed to work, doesn't mean it is safe or reliable.

Comment: fair comment @Enigmativity. So is there any way we can ensure FormB gets a chance to update progress when multiple copies of FormA are so busy?

Comment: @bmadtiger - The answer is to never make any form busy. Push all of the non-UI work to another thread.

Comment: @bmadtiger - Without a [mcve] I can't say any more.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I'm confused. You said earlier you wanted a more minimal example - now you're saying you don't have enough to run it. Can you please explain what more I need to do to get some help here.

Comment: @bmadtiger - It was Peter Duniho who asked for a minimal example. He did not ask for a "more minimal" example. Right now you don't have enough detail for us to create a project and run your code and see your issue.